# How to add Confirm Message in Ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

i need the Confimation box. it should display the message "do you want to delete the record".if it is yes delete .no message will be closed that is the simple thing have you do it. what i tried the coding below i attached please go through the code. when i ran the code no output will be displayed. can you give the good solution for it thanks.

```
function RemoveTeam(id) {

 $.confirm({
    buttons: {
        hey: function () {



            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'remove.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function (data) {


                    get_all();

                },

            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            alert(xhr.responseText);
            //
            }

            });
            }, }
        }
    }
```

Comment: which confirm do you used

Comment: Do you want delete the record? this is the confirm message need to display

Comment: can you write the code please?

Comment: check beforeSend in "duplicated" accepted answer.

Comment: i checked sir. my coding i don't know how to write

Comment: @paypalkob please review my answer let me know your feedback and tell whether it will resolve your issue or not?

Comment: You only need add....    beforeSend:function(){
     return confirm("Do you want delete the record?");
},   before your.... error: function (xhr, status, error)

Comment: @paypalkob please review my answer it will probably help to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

As I have reviewed your jquery code it may use jquery-confirm plugin and code may help to resolve your issue. I used dummy JSON call to generate ajax request.

```js
function removeTeam(id) {
  $.confirm({
    buttons: {
      hey: function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/bower.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          method: 'get'
        }).done(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }).fail(function(err) {
          console.log('Something went wrong.');
        });
      },
      cancel: function() {
        console.log('the user clicked cancel');
      }
    }
  });
}
removeTeam(10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
function RemoveTeam(id) {
    var r =  confirm("do you want to delete the record");
    if (r == true) {




            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'remove.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function (data) {


                    get_all();

                },

            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            alert(xhr.responseText);
            //
            }

            });

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```